# Performance tuning for on premises postgreSql to blob

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to move data from On premises Postgres to blob incrementally, but the data is moving very slow, are there any performance tuning steps to be followed?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow..!

I would suggest that you take these steps to tune the performance of your Data Factory service with Copy Activity:

**Establish a baseline:** During the development phase, test your pipeline by using Copy Activity against a representative data sample. Collect execution details and performance characteristics following Copy activity monitoring.

**Diagnose and optimize performance:** If the performance you observe doesn't meet your expectations, you need to identify performance bottlenecks. Then, optimize performance to remove or reduce the effect of bottlenecks.

**Expand the configuration to your entire data set:** When you're satisfied with the execution results and performance, you can expand the definition and pipeline to cover your entire data set.

For more details, refer  [Performance tuning steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#performance-tuning-steps) to learn about key factors that impact performance of data movement (Copy Activity) in Azure Data Factory and various ways to optimize it.

Hope this helps.